# jQuery hover change arrows on sorting options

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover, flags, mouseout

I've developping on my website a way of sorting divs (.ligne) with various sorting options. sort by name, by date, by status, and by type. I have a jquery code that works well. When Clicking on the sorting options the arrow direction change (ASC /DSC), everything is perfect.

Now i'm trying when mouseover a sorting options (the ones that are not active) to make an arrow appears (ASC), and when mouseout make it disappear. It tried something which works but not fine...

for example when mouseover on YEAR when my divs are sorted by "PROJECTS", the arrow down appears and when mouseout it disappear. that's ok. then when clicking on "YEAR" to sort by "YEAR", my arrow down appears, and stays. that's fine. but when I click again, then my divs are sorted in reversed order, and the arrow up appears, but when I mouseover the "YEAR" again, my arrow down re appears... and that's my problem with all my sorting options...

here is a jsfiddle without the mouseover and mouseout problem just for you to understand what I've achieved so far :

http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/813/

and here is the jquery code I'm working on for the mouseover and mouseout :

```
/* VILLE */

$('#projet').mouseover(function () {
if (flag_ville == 0) {
      $("#nom_ASC").show();
}
});

$('#projet').mouseout(function () {
if (flag_ville == 0) {
      $("#nom_ASC").hide();
}
});

/* ANNEE */

$('#annee').mouseover(function () {
if (flag_annee == 0) {
      $("#annee_ASC").show();
}
});

$('#annee').mouseout(function () {
if (flag_annee == 0) {
      $("#annee_ASC").hide();
}
});

/* STATUT */

$('#statut').mouseover(function () {
if (flag_statut == 0) {
      $("#statut_ASC").show();
}
});

$('#statut').mouseout(function () {
if (flag_statut == 0) {
      $("#statut_ASC").hide();
}
});

/* TYPE */

$('#type').mouseover(function () {
if (flag_type == 0) {
      $("#type_ASC").show();
}
});

$('#type').mouseout(function () {
if (flag_type == 0) {
      $("#type_ASC").hide();
}
});
```

and a jsfiddle with this code added :

http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/814/

I'm using flags for the first part of my code, and that's why I tried to use them for the second part, but it's not working, and I can't find a solution...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why using Javascript ? You could do it with CSS.

Instead of :

```
<div class="col-xs-3 text-right" id="projet">
    <div class="title">PROJECT</div>
    <span id="nom_ASC" class="sort">&#8595;</span>
    <span id="nom_DSC" class="sort">&#8593;</span>
</div>
```

You could try :

```
<div class="col-xs-3 title" id="projet">
    PROJECT
    <span id="nom_ASC" class="sort">&#8595;</span>
    <span id="nom_DSC" class="sort">&#8593;</span>
</div>
```

and :

```
div.title > span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: whatever you want px;
    right: whatever you want px;
}

div.title:hover > span {
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

I have updated your jsfiddle with my proposition: http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/818/
With CSS classes instead of flags, it's clearer.

Or maybe you could prefer that one : http://jsfiddle.net/C2heg/817/

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I don't know how to use your solution with my first part of code... could you maybe try on jsfiddle ? may help, thanks again

Comment: I edited my answer to add the jsfiddle.

J'espère que cela pourra t'aider. ^^

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's not exactly what I was looking for but it helped me finding a solution combining flags and css classes ! thanks a lot for your contributions.

Comment: So, could you answer your own question with the solution you found to close it ?